# Python code only copying data from second workbook using openpyxl - issue with first workbook?

Tags: python, excel, operating-system, openpyxl

Why is my Python code only able to copy data from the second workbook and not from the first workbook using openpyxl, even though the code seems to be written correctly?

The code is divided in three blocks:

**Block 1: Importing libraries and setting up paths**

This block imports necessary libraries such as openpyxl, os, and re. The paths for the input and output directories are also set up using the input_path and output_path variables.

```
import openpyxl
import os
import re

input_path = r'C:\\Users\\input'
output_path = r'C:\\Users\\output'
res = []
```

**Block 2: Defining functions**
This block defines the following functions:

**subs(file_name)**
This function takes a file_name as input and replaces the year value in the filename with an underscore. It returns the modified filename.

**get_data(file_path)**
This function takes a file_path as input and checks if the year value in the filename is 2021 or 2022. If it's 2021, it loads the workbook and the sheet named "DRE" and copies the data to the worksheet named "_2021" of the newly created workbook. If it's 2022, it loads the workbook and the sheet named "DRE" and copies the data to the worksheet named "_2022" of the newly created workbook. Finally, it saves the newly created workbook with the copied data to the output directory. The function returns the file_path if the year value is valid, otherwise, it returns None.

**Block 3: Interacting with the input directory**
This block uses a for loop to iterate through all the files in the input directory. For each file, it checks if the object is a file, and if it is, it adds the filename to the res list.

```
# interact with the directory
for p in os.listdir(input_path):
    # checar se o obejto atual é um arquivo
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(input_path, p)):
        res.append(p)
```

**Block 4: Main logic**
This block uses a for loop to iterate through all the filenames in the res list. For each filename, it creates a new workbook with two worksheets named "_2021" and "_2022" using the openpyxl library. It then loads the newly created workbook and assigns the worksheets to the ws21 and ws22 variables respectively. It calls the get_data() function to copy the data from the original Excel file to the newly created Excel file.

```
for r in res:
    nw = openpyxl.Workbook()
    file = str(r)
    file = subs(file)
    nw.create_sheet('_2021')
    nw.create_sheet('_2022')
    nw.save(output_path + '\\' + file)

    wbn = openpyxl.load_workbook(output_path + '\\' + file, data_only=True)
    ws21 = wbn['_2021']
    ws22 = wbn['_2022']

    get_data(input_path + '\\' + r)
```

Summarizing, the code reads Excel files from a directory, creates new Excel files, and copies data from the original files to the newly created files.

**FULL CODE**

```
import openpyxl
import os
import re

input_path = r''
output_path = r''
res = []

def subs(file_name):
    if re.search(r' 2021 ', file_name):
        file_name = file_name.replace(' 2021 ', '_')
    elif re.search(r' 2022 ', file_name):
        file_name = file_name.replace(' 2022 ', '_')
    return file_name

def get_data(file_path):
    if re.search(r' 2021 ', file_path):
        data = file_path
        wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(data, data_only=True)
        ws = wb['DRE']

        for row in ws:
            for cell in row:
                ws21[cell.coordinate].value = cell.value

        wbn.save(output_path + '\\' + file)
    
    elif re.search('2022', file_path):
        data = file_path
        wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(data, data_only=True)
        ws = wb['DRE']

        for row in ws:
            for cell in row:
                ws22[cell.coordinate].value = cell.value

        wbn.save(output_path + '\\' + file)

    else:
        data = None
    return data

# interagir com o diretório apresentado
for p in os.listdir(input_path):
    # checar se o obejto atual é um arquivo
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(input_path, p)):
        res.append(p)

for r in res:

    nw = openpyxl.Workbook()
    file = str(r)
    file = subs(file)
    nw.create_sheet('_2021')
    nw.create_sheet('_2022')
    nw.save(output_path + '\\' + file)
    # nw.close()

    # Planilha compilada com as abas de 2021 e 2022
    wbn = openpyxl.load_workbook(output_path + '\\' + file, data_only=True)
    ws21 = wbn['_2021']
    ws22 = wbn['_2022']

    get_data(input_path + '\\' + r)
```

Comment: The simple reason; there is a for loop, **for r in res:** which loops the 'found' xlsx files as variable r. In this for loop you create the workbook and two sheets. Then copy the values from the r file, sheet 'DRE' to this new workbook with and save. So that is found file 1, Sheet 'DRE' copied. Then you run through the loop again with the next found file as r, and do the same thing; ***create a new workbook with two sheets and save***. Considering it's the same name for the workbook you've just overwritten the previously saved workbook with a new empty workbook with two sheets.

Comment: <continued> Then this found file sheet DRE, get copied and saved again. Thus only the last copied sheet will be in the new workbook as each previous sheet is gone each time that loop is run creating the workbook, worksheets, then saving. Therefore if file 1 wrote to sheet '_2021' and file 2 to sheet '_2022' you will only have sheet _2022 populated.

Comment: <continued>You need to create the workbook ***one time only*** so it should be external to that or any loop. You also do not need to keep saving constantly. There are 3 saves in the code, you only need to save the new workbook **once** at the end of copying all the data before exiting the code.

Answer (score 0):

Along with previous comments this Example Code shows how to make  this more efficient.
I don't know the name of your original xlsx files other than they appear to include a year date like `'_2021_'` and `'_2022_'`, or how many sheets each has. This code should manage this and just copy the Sheets with name `'DRE'` to the new workbook, name it from the first file name with date removed and save.

Code operation;

1. The ***subs*** function and section with comment ***interagir com o diretório apresentado*** seem unnecesary.
   There will only be one name for the new workbook so this can just be taken from the first file in a similar way. To create this file name, in case this file includes '*2021*', '*2022*' or even '*2023*' the regex pattern can be changed to look for the date starting with 20 followed by 2 digits surrounded underscore to remove. The file name is generated when processing the first file.
   The ***res*** list is no longer used in your updated code so this section is no longer needed and not used in this example.
2. To copy the sheets we loop through the found xlsx file names. Since I don't know what filenames may exist in **input_path**, I have created the files list from files in the input_path which include the numerals '20' and have extension .xlsx. This might not be sufficient to filter to the specific files you want so this filtering can be extended if needed.
   For now we'll assume that the list contains just the files you want to copy from.
3. Considering the new workbook is a copy of sheets from existing workbooks, rather than create a new sheet and copy each sheet from each workbook in turn, the new workbook can start as a copy of the first file minus any unwanted sheets. Therefore on the first iteration of the **files** loop, which we determine from **file_count**, the **new_wb** object is the workbook created from opening the `first xlsx file`. If there are sheets in this first file other than 'DRE' (which I assume you don't want), loop through the sheets deleting all, except the 'DRE' sheet which is renamed to **'dre_{file date}'**.
   ***If the xlsx files only have sheet 'DRE' then the sheet deletion can be skipped and just do the sheet rename.***
   That is the first 'DRE' sheet copied from the first xlsx file completed.
4. On the second loop of files, for the next 'DRE' sheet we will need to copy the cell values to a new sheet in the new workbook. The `source sheet` again is known so we can select that directly and the `target sheet` can be created and named from the `file name date`. Then we copy the sheet values cell by cell to this new sheet.
5. On completion of copying the values the loop will cycle onto the next file if it exists, and complete step 4 again. If no more files exist the new workbook is saved and the code run ends.

So you can see this is much simplified and quicker and the number of sheets copied cell by cell is reduced by 1.
There is no need to close the source workbook after you copy the cells, in fact **wb.close** does nothing unless the file is opened as `read-only` or `write-only` anyway.
The new workbook created/opened once and saved at the end after the data is copied.

```
import openpyxl
import os
import re


def file_date(f):
    return re.findall('20[\d]{2}', f)[0]


input_path = r'F:\PycharmProjects\Stack7\Stack1\ExcelFiles'
output_path = r'F:\PycharmProjects\Stack7\Stack1\OutExcelFiles'

new_filename = ''
sheet_name = 'DRE'
### Get files list where the file name includes '20' and extension is .xlsx
files = [f for f in os.listdir(input_path) if '20' in f and f.endswith('.xlsx')]

for file_count, file in enumerate(files):
    data = []

    ### First workbook can become the new workbook
    if file_count == 0:
        ### New workbook has one name only, we can get this from the first wb
        new_filename = re.sub(r'_20[\d]{2}_', '_', file)
        ### New workbook is the first opened workbook
        new_wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(os.path.join(input_path, file), data_only=True)
        ### If there are other Sheets in the original workbook these can be removed
        ### The 'DRE' Sheet to keep is be renamed to 'dre_20{file date}
        for sheet in new_wb.sheetnames:
            if sheet != sheet_name:
                del new_wb[sheet]
            else:
                new_wb[sheet_name].title = f'{sheet_name.lower()}_{file_date(file)}'

    ### Second and subsequent files need to copy sheet to sheet
    else:
        ### Open next workbook 
        wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(os.path.join(input_path, file), data_only=True)

        ### Only want to copy sheet 'DRE' so just need to select that sheet as source
        source_sheet = wb[sheet_name]
        ### Sheet to copy to is new. Rename to 'dre_{file date}
        target_sheet = new_wb.create_sheet(f'{sheet_name.lower()}_{file_date(file)}')

        ### Copy cell data from source to target cell by cell
        for (row, col), source_cell in source_sheet._cells.items():
            target_cell = target_sheet.cell(column=col, row=row)
            target_cell.value = source_cell.value

### Save the new file one time
new_wb.save(f'{output_path}\\{new_filename}')
```